# How do I find the value for the selected row in datagrid in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get value of selected value in Datagrid in C#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int index = datagridview1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
DataGridViewRow row1 = datagridview1.Rows[index];   
string str = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[Column name].Value);
```

Comment: Thanx Vivek. It Solved my Problem

Comment: Happy to help you Rahul

Answer (score 0):

please be specific in asking questions. adding existing codes may help you better.

`DataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].value` might be what you need

Answer (score 0):

**I Found My Answer in my way**
Do  this Coding on Data Grid Cell Clicked Event

```
int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
String id = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Do this coding on `Data Grid` Cell Click Event `row.Cells[0]` it Contains the Column of which I want my Value.